# Android sliding tabs - 2 line text on tabs

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I came across this image online and I was wondering: is it possible to have a two line text view for one of my tabs within my sliding tabs project?

[image: dual line tab]

**Hello tab error**

[image: Hello tab error]

**DeafultTabView code**

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    textView.setWidth(size.x / 2); // (size.x / number of textviews);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
        // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
        textView.setAllCaps(true);
    }

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in the `TextView` returned from `createDefaultTabView()` method

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Line one <br/>Line two"));
```

set text like this (Generic condition)

```
private void setCustomText(TextView textView, String[] msg, boolean isSingleLine){
    if(isSingleLine)
        textView.setText(msg[0]);
    else
        textView.setText(TextUtils.join("<br/>", msg));
}
```

Comment: I have 2 tabs in my sliding tabs project. I don't want 2 lines for both of them - I only want 2 lines for 1 of those tabs.

Comment: What about for 4 tabs? 1st tab text: Hello; 2nd tab text:[1st line]Hello [2nd line]World; 3rd tab text:[1st line]Hello [2nd line]Europe; 4th tab text:[1st line]Hello [2nd line]London.

Comment: Update it for generic condition

Comment: Cool. Although when I select the 'Hello' tab, the dark grey box that appears doesn't seem to be covering the whole of the touchable app (a bit of light grey appears just above the red line). Is there anyway of fixing this?

Comment: Adjust you layout Param for TextView in method createDefaultTabView() method. Also if it solved your issue please accept it as answer.  :-)

Comment: I haven't used any layout Param at all for TextView and I don't know what kind of Layout to mention in the code.

Comment: Can you post code for method `createDefaultTabView()` ??

Comment: Code is attached in the section titled **DeafultTabView code**.

Comment: Try commenting line `textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);`

Comment: I think this is because some of tabs have higher height than first one. I guess you should set it height to match with its parent. A rough guess.

Comment: Your new issue is that there is some margin below the textview, right? Can you post a new question for it? This question should address only what it was intended for. I ll be happy to help you there too. Post new question link here.

Comment: No worries. I've solved the issue. All i needed was `\n` in the code for the tab names.